# Prove that the application $r:B(0,\delta)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, defined as $r(h)=f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)\cdot h$, is differentiable in $h=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, applications

If $U\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ be open, let $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ differentiable in $x_0\in U$. Consider a open ball $B(x_0,\delta)$, with it's center $x_0$ and radius $\delta$ such that $B(x_0,\delta)\subset U$. Prove that the application $r:B(0,\delta)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, defined as
$$r(h)=f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)\cdot h,$$
is differentiable in $h=0$.

I proved by definition, but some doubts arose. I'll show my proof and after that, I'll leave my questions.

Proof: First, let's find a face for the derivative applied to $k\in\mathbb{R}^m$.
$$r'(0)\cdot k=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{r(0+tk)-r(0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+tk)-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)\cdot tk -(f(x_0+0)-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)\cdot 0)}{t}=$$
$$=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+tk)-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)\cdot tk -f(x_0+0)+f(x_0)+f'(x_0)\cdot 0}{t}=$$
As $f$ is differentiable in $x_0\in U$, then $f'(x_0)$ is a linear transformation and therefore $f'(x_0)\cdot 0=0$. So we have
$$=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+tk)-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)\cdot tk }{t}=$$
As $t\in\mathbb{R}$, and $f'(x_0)\cdot k$ exists, then:
$$=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+tk)-f(x_0)}{t}-\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f'(x_0)\cdot tk }{t}=f'(x_0)\cdot k-f'(x_0)\cdot k=0.$$
$$\Rightarrow r'(0)\cdot k=0.$$

Now all that remains is to show that the rest goes to zero, ie,

$$\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{r(0+w)-r(0)-r'(0)\cdot w}{|w|}=0.$$

Indeed:

$$\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{r(0+w)-r(0)-r'(0)\cdot w}{|w|}=\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{r(w)-r(0)-0}{|w|}=\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{r(w)-r(0)}{|w|}=$$
$$=\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+w)-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)\cdot w-f(x_0)+f(x_0)+f'(x_0)\cdot 0}{|w|}.$$
As $f$ is differentiable in $x_0$, so $f'(x_0)$ is a linear transformation and therefore $f'(x_0)\cdot 0=0$. Hence, we have:
$$\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{r(0+w)-r(0)-r'(0)\cdot w}{|w|}=\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{f(x_0+w)-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)\cdot w}{|w|}=0.$$

My doubts are:

1. Is that proof correct?
2. Where do I use the open balls?
3. Am I missing something?
4. Why is the information of $\delta$ important?
5. What's the function of the open ball in the domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open balls are enough to have a differentiation of r around 0.

Comment: You're right! I imagined that.